# Correlated variables and scipy curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, correlation, curve-fitting, model-fitting

I have a physical model with one independent variable `X` and three parameters `A`, `B` and `C`. The dependent variable is `Y=F(X,A,B,C)` where `F` is the model's function which is smooth and continuous.

I have many files with data points `(X,Y)` that I want to fit (each file) with the model to study how the parameters change. The model is non-linear with respect to the independent variable and all the parameters.

To fit the model, I use `scipy.optimize curve_fit` in Python inside a `for loop` throughout the files with the data points. For each file, I get the best fitting parameters `(A,B,C)` and the model fits great to all the files. However, when I check the parameter errors after the fittings, I notice that the errors in `A` are really large, even two orders of magnitude higher than the corresponding values.

The experience tells me that these large variances might be due to the fact that the parameter `A` could be correlated to any of the others. To check this assumption, I plotted the obtained values of `A` against the values of `B` and `C`. I see that, in fact, a power-law relation of the form `A=a*B^b` arises, which is physically acceptable.

Is there a way to tell `curve_fit` to take care of this correlation without having to introduce new parameters (say `a` and `b`) in order to fit the model with the lowest variance possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `method = 'trf'` as a parameter for your fit. This avoids using least squares and works with pseudoinverse of the Jacobian. I believe a Jacobian with a zero eigenvalue then should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks.
I tried it but it gives me the same large variance for A.